# Can't seem to find a solid regex for a URL spam remover

Tags: regex, url, preg-replace

I can't seem to find any decent simple regexes for removing spam links. One I am trying works, but only if the www.example.com doesnt have a period and another sentence next to it.
I have a good book on regexes, but simply don't have the time to learn it all atm.

Here is the regex I am using. I'm honestly not sure if i am even doing this right.

```
        $a = $_POST['msge'];
    $b = preg_replace('^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$^', '[LINK REMOVED]', $a);
    print $b;
```

So, what I was wondering was, if the code looks right, does anyone have a better regex that I could use?

Comment: Do you want to remove *any*  link? Or is there a special rule for determining which links are spam and which links are ham?

Comment: Your regex currently finds links only if they are at the end of the file (because of the `$` anchor). Also, you'd better not use `^` as a regex delimiter because that's an important metacharacter in a regex. Better use `~` or `%` if you don't want to use the standard `/`.

Comment: Yeah, Id like to remove any links, none are allowed on my form.

Comment: Careful, the regex won't find loads of valid links.

Answer (score 0):

Tim answered my question. He wrote:

Your regex currently finds links only if they are at the end of the file (because of the $ anchor). Also, you'd better not use ^ as a regex delimiter because that's an important metacharacter in a regex. Better use ~ or % if you don't want to use the standard /

Answer (score 0):

It's [impossible to detect all links](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) in text reliably. Especially if you want to find links without a protocol (`bit.ly/foo` etc.).

You can find more (but never all) links with

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\b
    (?:
     (?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/  # protocol (optional)
     |www\.|ftp\.|bit\.        # add more typical "link starters" here
    )
    [-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*
    [A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]
    /ix', 
    '[LINK REMOVED]', $subject);
```